# Temperature limit of the increase in heat

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature

If the sun is the hottest known thing to humans is it possible to have a temperature greater than the sun?.

Comment: Sun is not the hottest thing known to humans.

Comment: If not that then what is?

Comment: @user31903 Currently the hottest thing we know of is are laser stimulated particles of an ultracold gas of potassium, with a temperature of a few billionths of a degree below absolute zero.

Comment: @DavidH, isn't this the coldest? And billionths of a degree *above* zero?

Comment: No to both questions. [Negative temperatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature) are hotter than positive ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sun isn't the hottest known thing. We can make hotter temperatures than even the center of the sun in the lab.  It's just a matter of putting a lot of energy into a small space.

You might be getting confused with the physical law that you cannot concentrate heat from a black body to a higher temperature than the source. So you cannot focus sunlight onto a spot and get a higher temperature than the surface of the sun - since otherwise the heat would flow from your hotspot back to the sun and heat it!

edit: the lab record is something like a few million-million degrees, a million times hotter than even the center of the sun (15 Million deg). Although at this point the definition of temperature gets a bit tricky.